# How to set custom tick interval and labels on date x.axis on standard plot

Tags: r, date, plot, axis-labels

I'm working on an animal tracking time series dataset.

I'm trying to plot the date (x axis) on top of the graph (side=3) instead of below as automatically done by R with the plot function. However, I would like the tick intervals to be similar to the below axis (or ideally 7-day intervals) instead of showing everyday ticks like it currently does on the top axis. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

This is probably trivial... Sorry if the answer is obvious to some of you.

Code below:

```
quartz(width = 8,height = 3.5);

plot(DATE,tag$Depth, type='l', ylim=c(ymax,ymin), xlab="Date",ylab="Depth (m)");

axis(side=3, labels=DATE, at=DATE);
# works but I need to only show one date/tick every week
```

I know I need to specify something different for the at= expression, but since it needs to be the same as the labels= expression I can't seem to work out the syntax. I tried defining the set of dates to be displayed as follows, but without success so far...

```
newDATE <- seq(as.Date(DATE[1], format = "%d/%m/%Y"), tail(as.Date(DATE), 1), by = "week")
```

Suggestions welcome! Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can use `axTicks(1)` after your initial plot to get the tickmark points on existing x axis.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I eventually managed to do what I was after using the below code: Thanks for your help. I managed to solve the issue with the below code:                                                                             quartz(width = 8,height = 3.5)
plot(DATE,tag$Depth, type='n', ylim=c(ymax,ymin), las=1, xaxt='n',xlab="",ylab="Depth (m)") # first plot
axis(side=3, at=DATE[seq(1,length(DATE), length.out=5)], labels=DATE[seq(1,length(DATE), length.out = 5)])